# Resource Exhausted OOM while loading VGG16

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, gpu

I am apologizing in advance if this issue seems to basic, but I am new to Tensorflow and appreciate any help.

I find that I have to frequently keep rebooting my computer to be able to load models such as VGG16 from keras.applications. I have a fairly high-end machine with 4 GeForce GTX 1080 Ti GPUs and Intel® Core™ i7-6850K CPU @ 3.60GHz × 12 for my CPU and use it only for Tensorflow (through Keras).

As soon as I reboot I will be able to successfully load models (such as VGG16) and train on large training datasets. But, if I let my computer sit idle for a while and rerun the same program, I will get a resource exhausted message (OOM) which can be fixed by rebooting my computer again. It is extremely frustrating to keep rebooting my computer every couple of hours. Does anyone know what's going on and how to solve this issue?

Comment: did you try running nvidia-smi when you are running out of memory? It should allow you to check GPU memory usage. If the problem not with GPU try extending your memory page file to give it some extra room

Comment: ' try extending your memory page file' : can you please tell me how to do this in ubuntu 16.04. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry, swap file is the correct name of the thing. Here is one description of the process: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-space-on-ubuntu-16-04    Generally, it would be better to simply have enough memory, but we will stay positive and hope that all the 'junk' load will go into swap and actual training will use RAM directly

Comment: Did you try instead of restarting your computer to restart your kernel?

Comment: Do you use `jupyter notebook`?

Comment: Hi @MarcinMożejko yes, I use jupyter notebooks.

Comment: @IoannisNasios I've tried that several times and restarting kernel does not solve the problem.

Comment: It may be interesting to check your tensorflow and keras versions. I heard that old versions had memory leakages, also, check if you aren't using any other GPU consuming program, such as high performance video players, image editors, CAD programs, etc.

Comment: did you try `K.clear_session()` and then `del model` ? could be a possible workaround (not real solution though)

Comment: @DanielMöller It seems this issue does not only happen with Keras. As the user who has put the bounty is someone else (other than OP) and has stated this in the bounty notice: "The same issue arises with PyTorch".

Comment: @DanielMöller The issue arises with the newest version of PyTorch as well. No other programs are running.

Comment: @ArsenyLevin In my case for PyTorch, I do clear the cache when necessary and keep track of the used and cached memory but that's not the issue.

Comment: Note that this issue seems to only arise when using jupyter notebooks and not when running the code in Python in the terminal or from a .py file.

Comment: What happens if you restart the jupyter notepad server?

Comment: @BramVanroy usually when I use Pytorch for building my training model I use
`device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")` and use this device variable. Coz it so happens that usually system as per availability of resources switches between cpu and cuda. So I have this check implemented before each epoch training. Other than that for training I usually end up using Colab of Google as its faster than my system.

Comment: @Jerin I hav ethe same `device` declaration. I don't use Colab because it is slower than my system.

Comment: @Digital-Thinking When restarting the whole computer, everything works again. But that's not practical of course. Seems that when using a notebook, the cache of the GPU is not cleared.

Comment: How much RAM do you have?

Comment: @Strom 32GB of DDR4.

Comment: can  you post the output of these commands when this occurs? $free -mh $cat /proc/meminfo $vmstat

Comment: @carlsborg I'm on Windows, so that won't work I'm assuming.

Comment: @BramVanroy sorry didn't see that, OP commented they were on Ubuntu. Have you tried disabling output caching in Jupyter notebook? Also pytorch has  empty_cache() which should delete unused memory.

Comment: I have tried the `torch.cuda.empty_cache()` to no avail (after explicitly `del` a variable first). I'll try disabling output caching but I'm not sure how that will help.

Comment: If your set up is different from OP, it would be better to start a new question and post complete description and logs from your experiment.

Answer (score 1):

If you have batch size > 1, try to use lower batch size, which could lower the memory requirements gor GPU.

Also, if you end with working with the network, check the GPU memory by `nvidia-smi`, if it was released or not. If not, kill the process which loaded the network (usually some python interpreter).